# How do I float an image next to a paragraph properly?

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, paragraph

I have a part in my website where there is a column of icons with a paragraph next to them. Ive been searching the internet for a simple solution, but everything seems to either not work or messes up my webpage. This is the last thing I've tried:

```css
#exw
{
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 float: left;
}

#exx
{
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 float: left;
}

#exy
{
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 float: left;
}

#floats
{
 width: auto;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 530px;
 margin-top: 13px;

}



#floats img
{
 margin-top: 22px;
 
}
```

```html
<div id="floats"> 
<p><img id="exw" src="example.jpg"/>
<p>example</p>

  <p><img id="exx" src="example.jpg"/>
<p>example</p>
  
  <p><img id="exy" src="example.jpg"/>
<p>example</p>
  
</div>
```

I'm sure there is a ridiculously simple solution to my problem, but I can't figure it out. Anybody have an idea of what I did wrong? Thanks!

**PS-** I'm also sure there is an easier way to write the code I used (like "class" instead of separate id's for the icons). I'm working on that...

Comment: remove float:right from #floats and see

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code is wrong you did not close the `<p>` tag, and modify some css like this:

```css
#exw
{
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 float: left;
}
#floats > p {float:left;margin:0;}
#floats > p + p{margin-top:10px;}
#floats > p:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
clear: both;
}

#exx
{
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 float: left;
}

#exy
{
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 float: left;
}

#floats
{
 width: auto;
// float: right;
// margin-right: 530px;
 margin-top: 13px;

}
```

```html
<div id="floats"> 
<p><img id="exw" src="example.jpg"/></p>
<p>example</p>

  <p><img id="exx" src="example.jpg"/></p>
<p>example</p>
  
  <p><img id="exy" src="example.jpg"/></p>
<p>example</p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but one more thing...how would align the paragraph with the image in the middle? In your example, the paragraphs are too high...

Comment: @George Now you can define line-height according to your content